# How to extract only number from a variable

Tags: jquery

For a variable i can i have 3 possible  values as response from back end

```
var discount_div = '40   percent off ';

OR

var discount_div = '0 ';

OR

var discount_div = '108  Rs off';
```

I need to extract only the number from the variable .

I have tried this way , its working , but it seems buggy

```
if (discount_div.indexOf("percent") > -1) 
{
discount_div = discount_div.replace("   percent off ", "");
}

else if (discount_div.indexOf("Rs") > -1) 
{
discount_div = discount_div.replace("  Rs off ", "");
}

else if (discount_div=='0') 
{
discount_div = discount_div
}
```

please let em know , if  there is   a efficient way of doing this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/L2ptm24o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
parseInt(discount_div,10)
```

This will return the first number in the string:

```
'40   percent off '     =    40
'0 '                    =     0
'108  Rs off'           =   108

'40 and 20'             =    40
'text only'             =   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parseInt` to get only numeric values

like this

```
parseInt(discount_div)
```

Comment: Is better practice to declare and the radix as second argument to prevent unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var str = "40   percent off"; 
var res = parseInt(str.slice(0,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` method:

```js
var str = '100 rupees off';
var num = str.match(/(\d)+/g)[0]

document.body.innerHTML = num; // +num  to convert to number.
```